# CSS Height: 20px + padding-bottom: 3px = 20px?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, height

I have css height problem with Firefox.

I have input `type="submit"` on my page and `height:20px, padding-bottom:3px.`
So firebug shows that button has `height 17px` and `padding-bottom: 3px` so total height is **20px** instead of **23px**.

Can anybody help me figure out whether this is problem with firefox or firebug?

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/tKZ5Y/
You can check the rendered submit button with Firebug

Comment: Can you setup a demo page for us to look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding is the "margin" that is included **inside** box. Margin is **outside** box.

Padding inside `<input>` will simply align text inside the input. If u use padding-top and padding-bottom 10px and text 10px then the text will be in the middle of a 30px container.

Also be aware that Firefox places text inside submit input a bit lower than all other browsers. There is a fix for it though.

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed: I think that your anwer was downvoted because it didn't correctly describe how the box model works.

Comment: @Guffa: I first provided the link in the answer, then I edited it to include more information about the model, but that didn't work...anyway, it doesn't matter now :-)

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed: The box model doesn't explain how padding is applied to buttons, and your information about the model was not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Padding works differently for buttons (and most form fields). The padding is is included in the width and height (except when the width is dynamic (i.e. the default for buttons), then the padding is added to the width).

I just [tested this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/3dsxD/) in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera, and it is consistent across all.

The only difference is that Opera reacts a bit differently when the height gets to small for the text, i.e. centering it vertically instead of placing it below the top padding.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin instead of padding.. padding is set inside the element contents margin is extended

Comment: Padding is not included in height (which was the main problem of IE6). Please refer to documentation

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem, it's a normal behavior of input components

Answer (score 0):

[PPK says it's a bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tests/mozie_button.html). Chrome doesn't seem to react in any way when I declare `padding-bottom` to a button, so... I don't know. The most important thing, I guess, is that you can get around this issue in Firefox and Opera (at least) using:

```
input[type=submit] {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit">` is styled as `-moz-box-sizing: border-box` in the UA stylesheet in Gecko, for website compat.  If you want a non-default behavior, then adjust the box-sizing styles accordingly.